# Getting wrong result from SHA256 than what is expected

Tags: javascript, cryptography, bitcoin, sha256, cryptojs

I am trying to derive a bitcoin address from a known public key. When hashing the public key with CryptoJS.SHA256 I don't get the expected result

```
CryptoJS.SHA256("0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6").toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
```

gets me:

> 32511e82d56dcea68eb774094e25bab0f8bdd9bc1eca1ceeda38c7a43aceddce

while i am trying to get:

> 600FFE422B4E00731A59557A5CCA46CC183944191006324A447BDB2D98D4B408

What am I missing?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to hash the binary representation, not a hexadecimal ascii string?

Comment: you can check the difference https://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm ... enter the string in `String hash` and you get what you're getting, enter your string in `Binary hash` and you'll get what you expect

Comment: When I run that on the command line, the first has, indeed, is the output. I don't think it's an encoding problem, but perhaps an inputs problem.

echo -n 0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6 | sha256sum
32511e82d56dcea68eb774094e25bab0f8bdd9bc1eca1ceeda38c7a43aceddce  -

Comment: @Sam It is an encoding problem, you also hashed the hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an encoding issue - don't try to hash the hex, hash the binary.

For example, here is the hash computation when you decode the hex into binary (using Haskell since I have it handy):

```
Prelude> import Crypto.Hash.SHA256
Prelude Crypto.Hash.SHA256> let str = "0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6"
Prelude Crypto.Hash.SHA256> Data.ByteString.Base16.encode $ hash $ fst $  Data.ByteString.Base16.decode $ Data.ByteString.Char8.pack str
"600ffe422b4e00731a59557a5cca46cc183944191006324a447bdb2d98d4b408"
```